# TableViewController only showing one dynamic section

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

For some reason, even though i have tried code copied from 3 different tutorials i am unable to get more then one section to appear in the table. I have been playing with it for hours but i cannot find the problem.

I have set the tableCell identifier correctly, even tried it in a fresh project doing it all from the start but no luck. The code i have used is below, the number of sections and rows i have hard coded while attempting to get this to work, but will not be the case.

```
import UIKit

class multiTableViewController: UITableViewController {

let section = ["pizza", "deep dish pizza", "calzone"]

let items = [["Margarita", "BBQ Chicken", "Pepperoni"], ["sausage", "meat lovers", "veggie lovers"], ["sausage", "chicken pesto", "prawns", "mushrooms"]]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {       
    return self.section[section]
}

 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    return cell

}
}
```

In this situation, the table will display The section header "pizza" and the three corresponding items but not the next three sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your `func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {`

by the below one :-

```
 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is the correct answer.
I have been starring at this for ages and did not notice that difference even after comparing everything else. It has taught me a very valuable lesson though.

Comment: @benllben :You very welcome :) Sometimes our mind gets saturated enough to not to notice such minute differences.